# Car won’t start randomly

Tags: engine, starting, car, pontiac, g6

I have a 2006 Pontiac g6 with 150,000 miles on it. Maybe once a day for the past couple weeks when I go to start it it will crank but not start. As soon as I attempt to start it again it starts up no problem. I used carburetor cleaner on it once and the problem stopped for a couple days. The car runs and drives smooth and it doesn’t idle hard at all. Does anyone know what this could be? It’s getting extremely annoying.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Recently, my '06 Silverado was doing the *same exact thing*. It would crank and crank and crank, but not start ... *sometimes*. Other times, it would start right up. Sometimes it would take one extra try to get it going, while others it seemed it would never start, but ultimately would. The other day, it just wouldn't start. The check engine light came on and stayed on. I read the codes and it was the crank position sensor. Not saying that's what going on with you, but your description sounds very similar. If there's a code, read it. That'll help.

Comment: When I go to read the codes, it only pulls up that it needs a new thermostat. I’m hoping this isn’t a major problem and can be fixed easily. I just bought this car about two months ago from a close friend.

Comment: Did you clear the thermostat code? (Also, a thermostat wouldn't keep it from starting, but might affect how it runs.)

Comment: Yeah, we’ve cleared it but everytime we do it comes back on. My boyfriend thinks it could possibly be the air filter and is gonna check it for me when he gets home.

Comment: An air cleaner wouldn't cause it not to start, but rather would affect how it runs. What *exactly* is the code you're getting (the alpha numeric)? If you could edit that into your question, please. Also, if you know somethings wrong (ie: thermostat), fix it. Might just save you a ton of diagnosing and you know it needs fixed anyway.

Comment: I had the same problem with my older 2002 ford explorer, it was getting pretty annoying... months later I found out that I had a gasket leak, so I rebuilt my engine, The camshaft sensor was gummed up with coolant... go figure :) take your car in to get the fuel injectors cleaned and test the cam, crankshaft sensors... I'm willing to bet it's one of those sensors that's having a hard time reading the shaft at the first go around... it's definitely not the filter... I mean if you have an advanced obd or oscilloscope you can test it yourself pretty easy

Comment: I live in a small town, so I’m not sure where to go to to get those things checked out. I have a feelings it’s something to do with what you have suggested. Hopefully that’s a pretty easy fix!

Comment: I'd be tempted to give seafoam a try. If it's a gummed up cam position sensor that could clean it off.

Comment: Both the cam and crank sensors are usually very easy fixes. Getting them diagnosed properly can sometimes be the trick (especially if there's no codes present). Don't just throw parts at your car (or let others do the same) as that will cost you extra money you wouldn't have otherwise needed to spend.

Comment: How do I check the cam and crank sensors?

Comment: With a oscilloscope or an advanced obd reader that can monitor the fluctuations, or you could remove the sensors and check to see if there's residue on them. Might be a lucky find. But you won't be able to test them just by taking them out and applying power

Comment: You also might want to check the PCV valve, it might be sticking on cold starts

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on my 350z. Found out it was the crankshaft sensor. Mine had 4 of them. Dont no how many u have but I found the one was causing problem fixed